# vbs and csv config file

Tags: csv, vbscript, config

I'm trying creating a hta script using vbs and a csv config file in order to have a launcher with delays between each launch.
then, it works but with some problems:
When I run the hta file, all softwares are launched at the same time, at thevery beginning.
After all the texts are shown with the delays respected.
The first objective was to make softwares launched with the respected delays and each text shown after each launch.
Last problem is at the end of reading csv file, the vbs script seems to stop and do, the hta doesn't close itself.

the csv file:

```
        Horloge,Nom,Delai,Soft,Resultat
MonTimer1,Start01,10000,C:\Program Files\IZArc\IZArc.exe,Izarc a bien été lancé
MonTimer2,Start02,15000,C:\Program Files\Moffsoft FreeCalc\MoffFreeCalc.exe,La calculatrice a bien été lancée
MonTimer3,Start03,20000,,All Tasks have been executed !
MonTimer4,Startfin,25000,,hta will now close !
```

hta file:

```
<!-- ----- ExeScript Options Begin -----
 ScriptType: window,invoker
 DestDirectory: temp
 Icon: D:\Bureau\startapp.bmp
 File: D:\Bureau\startapp.bmp
 ----- ExeScript Options End ----- -->

<head>
<title>Start App</title>

<HTA:APPLICATION
  APPLICATIONNAME="Start App"
  ID="startapp"
  VERSION="1.2"
  MAXIMIZEBUTTON="no"
  ICON="startapp.ico"
  SCROLL="no"
  SINGLEINSTANCE="yes"
  SELECTION="no"/>

<SCRIPT TYPE="text/javascript">
window.resizeTo(350,275);
window.moveTo(10,10);
</SCRIPT>

    <SCRIPT language="vbscript">

       Sub Window_onLoad
           StartTimer      
       End Sub

            Sub StartTimer
                MonTimer0 =window.setTimeOut ("welcome", 1000, "VBScript") 'Appel de MonScript
            End sub

                Sub Welcome
                    S = SetTimeOut("MaSub (""Vos applications vont se lancer dans un instant... Veuillez patienter..."")", 100)
                End Sub 


Dim Horloge
Dim Nom
Dim Delai
Dim Soft
Dim Resultat

Dim aVars 
aVars = Array( "Horloge", "Nom", "Delai", "Soft", "Resultat" ) 

Dim oFSO
Set oFSO = CreateObject( "Scripting.FileSystemobject" )

Const INPUT_FILE = "StartApp.csv"
Dim oStream
Dim sData
Dim aData



Set oStream = oFSO.OpenTextFile( INPUT_FILE )

oStream.SkipLine

Do While oStream.AtEndOfStream = False
    sData = oStream.ReadLine
    aData = Split( sData, "," )
    For i = 0 To UBound( aData ) 
        Execute aVars( i ) & " = " & Chr( 34 ) & aData( i ) & Chr( 34 ) 


    Next 
    'At this point all the vars referred to in aVars have the values
    'of the current record

    'START APP

    'WSCript.Echo Horloge, Nom, Delai, Soft, Resultat



Set WshShell = CreateObject ("Wscript.Shell")
WshShell.Run Chr(34) & soft

S = SetTimeOut("MaSub (" & Chr(34) & Resultat & Chr(34) & ")", Delai)   

'If oStream.AtEndOfStream = False Then
' window.close()
' End If

Loop

oStream.Close

</SCRIPT>



</head>

<Body STYLE="font:10 pt arial; color:white;filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Gradient(GradientType=1, StartColorStr='#000033', EndColorStr='#0000FF')" >

<p><center> <img src=".\startapp.bmp" /> </center></p>
<br/><br/><br/>

<p><center>
<span style="color:white">
<div id = D></div>

<script language = vbs>
Sub MaSub (E)
Document.All.D.innerHTML = E
ClearTimeOut S
End Sub
</script>
</center></p>

</span>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks if you could help me

Answer (score 0):

Use this instead of `setTimeOut`:

```
Set sh = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

Set oStream = oFSO.OpenTextFile( INPUT_FILE )
oStream.SkipLine
Do Until oStream.AtEndOfStream
  ...
  sh.Run Chr(34) & soft & Chr(34), 0, False
  sh.Run "ping -n " & (1+Delai/1000) & " 127.0.0.1", 0, True
Loop
```

**Note:** Using `Execute` for assigning values from one array (`aData`) to variable names from another array (`aVars`) is really, *really* ugly and makes your code unnecessarily difficult to read. I *strongly* recommend to either use `aData` directly or to use "normal" variable assignments instead:

```
Dim Horloge, Nom, Delai, Soft, Resultat
...
Do While oStream.AtEndOfStream = False
  aData = Split(oStream.ReadLine, ",")
  Horloge  = aData(0)
  Nom      = aData(1)
  Delai    = aData(2)
  Soft     = aData(3)
  Resultat = aData(4)
  ...
```